# What is the easiest method to import data into DGraph?

Tags: graph-databases, dgraph

What is the easiest way to get a large amount of data into DGraph and how do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at a relevant issue on the [DGraph github](https://github.com/dgraph-io/dgraph/issues/1323) which may provide how.  They cite https://blog.dgraph.io/post/scaling-dgraph/